# How can I use data in an input field as a filename?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to concoct a script for saving form submissions as a `.txt` file.  What I would like to do is use the person's first name as the file name it saves as.

So far I came up with this script:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','on'); ?><?php

$fileName= fopen($_Post['f_name'],'w');
$data= "";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= str_replace("_"," ",$key).":\n\n ". $value."\n\n\n\n";
}

fwrite($fileName, $data);
fclose($fileName);
?>
```

Here's the html I'm using to attempt it:

```
<form action="sender.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="f_name" name="first_name" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_1" name="Demo_01" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_2" name="Demo_02" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_3" name="Demo_03" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_4" name="Demo_04" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_5" name="Demo_05" />
    <input type="text" id="demo_6" name="Demo_06" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

This tells me that the way I'm telling it to post the name isn't registering in the code so there's nowhere for the fwrite to save the data.  Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: `$_Post` to `$_POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$fileName= fopen($_POST['first_name'],'w');
$data= "";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data.= str_replace("_"," ",$key).":\n\n ". $value."\n\n\n\n";
}

fwrite($fileName, $data);
fclose($fileName);
```

$_Post should be in uppercase and f_name should be first_name.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be **$_POST** (uppercase)

In addition, you need to use the **name**, not the **id**, in your case that would be *first_name*.